# Unable to insert data into MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am unable to insert data into MySQL database. I do not know the reason since no error is triggered. I am using XAMPP on windows to run local server. Here is the code. It would be great if someone could help.

I am always getting "Values not inserted" output. I also tried printing the $query when I got exact values I entered through a form in the VALUES ('$email', ...) part of the SQL query.

```
<?php


$dbconnect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","id3626001_login_details");

if (!$dbconnect) 
{
    die("Connection Failed" .mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (!mysqli_select_db($dbconnect, "id3626001_login_details"))
{
    echo "Could not connect to Database";
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['username']) && ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")){

$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];

// Inserting values into the database through a query
$query = "INSERT INTO user_registration (ID, email, username, password) VALUES ('$email', $username', '".md5($password)."')";

if (!mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query))
{   
    echo "Values not inserted";     
}

$result = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query);

if($result){
    echo "Registration Successful";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

there is a problem in your query,

**1)** your column counts and count of values you are passing are not the same (must be same

**2)** you forgot to put `'` (quote befor `$username'`)

change your query to

```
// Inserting values into the database through a query

$query = "INSERT INTO user_registration ( email, username, password) VALUES ('$email', '$username', '".md5($password)."')";
```

When you are testing you should not only print only query, you should also copy that query and run it directly into database through [(localhost/phpmyadmin)> select your databse  > SQL ] and see what error are displaying there when firing a query.

**UPDATE**

for @Akintunde 's suggestion

for security concerns you should not be using these kind of insertion methods which is fully open to [`SQL injections`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) you must follow some rule to avoid to get your script being target of sql injection

use [`Prepared Statements`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)  instead for database operations

Answer (score 1):

Here in your query you forgot to put upper quote `'`-> `$username'`,

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user_registration (email, username, password) VALUES ('$email', '$username', '".md5($password)."')";
```

Here we are not passing Id as a param so you need to make id auto increment in database for that table.

and why are to passing your query twice into mysqli_query() you can check for once like,

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query);
if ($result)
{   
  echo "Registration Successful";
}
else{
  echo "Values not inserted"; 
}
```

Comment: in your  query number of columns and values are different

Comment: Thanks @Irony Stack i edited my answer. thanks for pointing me.